# How do I check if a file is executable on Linux

Tags: linux, file, format, executable

I know Linux has a built-in binary executable formats such as **ELF**, **a.out**, **Shebang** etc. I also know that the user is able to add his own supported formats to the system in '/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc'.

Now my goal is to cover all the possibilities here, so I could automatically (with a script) determine if a program is executable or not (and **not** just by the runable permission bit). I heard of the command **file** that can identify the file's format, and that it will print out the word *'executable'* if it is an executable **however** - when I tested it with a **jar** file (which is listed on the binfmt_misc directory as an executable) it didn't print out the word *'executable'*.

So I am asking for the best way to determine if a file is executable on a Linux system. If there is a way to run execve() just to get the return code (if the file isn't a supported executable - execve returns a matching error) then I could just intercept it and use it. The thing is that I need to do it **without running the file on my system** (or at least not let it change it in any way...).

Thanks!

Comment: A `jar` file isn't executable, which is why `file` didn't say it was. It needs a java interpreter to execute it. Can you be more clear on what you mean by "executable"? You could, for example, have a Python script file which would execute via, `python myfile.py` but would fail to execute if you did, `sh myfile.py`. Is that considered executable?

Comment: broad question.. -x in linux is the answer. But what you would call executable for linux.. binary or a text file, which can be interpreted by an interpretr!! I guess both but even a file which doesnt hv executable permission can be executed as 'interpreter filename'.. since there are diff ways to execute you hv to consider all, and prepare a list of all!!!

Comment: I am not at all sure that your question really makes sense. What (and how) a file is executable is very system specific....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a file is executable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10319652/608639)