# bash command to check if a directory is executable

Tags: linux, permissions, bit, execution

My goal is to check if the the execution bit is not set for a directory.

I changed the permission of /tmp so that the execution bit is off.

```
root$: chmod 666 /tmp

root$: ls -l /
    ....
    .....    
    drw-rw-rw-  12 root root  4096 Feb 29 15:17 tmp
```

In my bash script, I have tried the following without success:

```
if [ ! -x /tmp ]; then 
......
```

I have experimented with all the suggestions at the following link, but the only different syntax approach does not work for me either:

```
if [[ ! -x /tmp] ; then
```

[check if a file is executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319652/check-if-a-file-is-executable)

These work as expected for regular files, but not for any directory, but I don't know why. Any ideas?

**Update #2**

I wrote a mini bash script with only the code suggested in a comment below.

Results:

```
[root@mc/]# cat tst.sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -x /tmp ]; then echo 'not executable!'; fi
exit

[root@mc/]# ./tst.sh
[root@mc/]#
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the code that you have provided in your question is correct (I just finished testing it myself).  It stands to reason, therefore, that something else in the script that is failing.  If you could, try running this simplified snippet:
`if [ ! -x /tmp ]; then echo 'not executable!'; fi`

As a quick side note, the "executable" flag for directories in Unix systems does not actually mean "executable".  It is actually the way that the directory is marked as searchable.  While I'm not sure if this will help with the problem you are working on, it is an interesting usage of existing fields.

Comment: check out update #2 in my post. I wrote a mini bash script with only your simplified snippet and then ran it. Nothing was output.

Comment: Hmm...  can you echo the permissions on /tmp again?  `ls -lAh /tmp`

Comment: drw-rw-rw-  12 root root  4096 Mar  1 13:15 tmp

Comment: What operating system and shell are you using?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11 (Tikanga). I am using bash.

Comment: Sorry about the delay.  I cannot acquire a copy of RHEL5 myself.  Could you please run `bash --version` and let me know what version it returns?  It is entirely possible that the version of bash does not support some part of the syntax.

Comment: GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not going to be able to test your script on even a remotely similar system - I cannot force Fedora to install a version of bash below 4.3.  I'd recommend updating Bash to version 4.3.x as it contains numerous security and bugfixes and then testing the script again.

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps use the find command to single out any directory without the executable bit

```
notex=$(find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -perm 666)
```

I think that may help..