# How to check if a file is executable in Bash

Tags: bash, ls

I am trying to build a condition that check if file has execute access bit set. I can't use grep and find.

I tried something with checking the "x" letter in the `ls -l` command but this is wrong in many cases.

```
for val in `ls $1`
do
  if [[ "`ls -l $1/$val`" -eq *w* ]]
  then
    rm $1/$val
  fi
done
```

Please help or give some advices!

Comment: Use `test -x file` or `[ -x file ]`.  See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20682162/6862601

Comment: ...and [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a file is executable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10319652/608639)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to parse the output of `ls` to see if a file is executable.  Shell provides the built-in `-x` check for that.  Using `-x` feature, your loop could be re-written as:

```
for file in "$1"/*; do
  [[ -x "$file" ]] && rm -- "$file"
done
```

---

See also:

- [How do I tell if a regular file does not exist in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638975/how-do-i-tell-if-a-regular-file-does-not-exist-in-bash)
- [As Charles suggested - Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- [BashFAQ/087 - How can I get a file's permissions (or other metadata) without parsing ls -l output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/087)

Comment: `"$1"/*`, you mean (to handle spaces in the directory name). And `rm -- "$file"`, if we want to handle the case where `$1` is a directory name that starts with a dash.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ -x "$file" ]; then
  # do something
fi
```

You can get many more options of file testing using `man` :

```
~]# man test
.... 
-x FILE
              FILE exists and execute (or search) permission is granted
```

Following should work:

```
 ~]# find $1 -type f | while IFS='' read -r -d '' p; 
     do 
        if [ -x "$p" ]; then 
           echo "removing $p";
           rm "$p";
        fi; 
     done
```

`find` command gets all the files (including `.`) in the directory given by `$1`. `while` reads each of these output, `if then` checks individual files for executable permission with`-x`.

### EDIT

After some comments, here is a swifter example:

```
find "$1" -type f -executable -exec rm -- {} \;
```

Comment: `[ -x $file ]` will falsely return true if `$file` is an empty string, because it will run `[ -x ]`, which tests if `-x` is an empty string (and, since it's non-empty, returns true). Use quotes: `[ -x "$file" ]`

Comment: This also isn't at all covering correctly/robustly retrieving filenames (```for val in `ls $1` ``` is full of known issues: won't handle names with spaces correctly, behavior with nonprintable characters varies between platforms, behavior with filenames containing newline literals is *entirely* undefined, etc).

Comment: Parsing the output of `find` fails in every instance where parsing the output of `ls` would, and it isn't even necessary. You can use the `-perm` primary to select the executable files, then use `-exec rm -- {} \;`  (or `-delete`, if supported) to remove them.

Comment: Quotes! `find "$1" -type f -executable -exec rm -- {} +` -- without the quotes around `$1`' a directory named `./My Directory` would be passed as two arguments, `./My` and `Directory`.

Comment: Also, `-exec rm -- {} \;` is inefficient, running `rm` once per file found, whereas `-exec rm -- {} +` invokes `rm` as few times as possible, putting multiple filenames onto the command line for each invocation.

Comment: If you *do* want to pipe from `find`, by the way, make it: `find "$1" -type f -print0 | while IFS='' read -r -d '' p; do` -- that way you correctly handle names with literal backslashes, names with trailing whitespace, and names with literal newlines, none of which the current `find ... | while read` can deal with. See also the "Actions In Bulk" section of [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind).