# How can I test if a file could be marked as executable and run?

Tags: linux, macos, linux-kernel, executable, elf

Is there a way to test whether a file, if I mark it as executable with `chmod +x file` and run it with `./file` will cause the operating system to execute it (or at least attempt to execute it), without actually executing it?

So far I have:

1. On Mac and Linux (or other Unix), test whether the first two bytes are `#!`.
2. On Linux, test whether the first four bytes are `0x7f454c46` (ELF magic number) and the `e_type` (offset `0x10`) is `ET_EXEC` (`0x0002`).
3. On Mac, check if the file is Mach-O and `filetype` is `MH_EXECUTE`. (Mach-O format is a bit more complicated and I haven't figured out the exact magic number(s) and offset for `filetype` yet.)
4. ...other executable formats?

Is there a way to do this more easily and correctly?

Comment: Under Linux, when correctly configured (e.g. using the binfmt mechanism), just about anything could potentially be executable. This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/); what is your goal here?

Comment: I have a *huge* tree of files many of which have the executable bit set when they shouldn't, and many of which don't have the executable bit set when they should. I think this is because a lot of the files were copied to/from filesystems without executable bits.

So I want all the files that could theoretically be executed to be executable and all the ones that couldn't to not be executable. It's not perfect but it's the closest I can get to being correct without manually going through every single file.

Comment: @larsks Is there a way to ask the kernel whether a given file would be accepted by its current binfmt configuration?

Comment: `man file` and running `file ...` can help here a bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a file is executable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10319652/608639)